# Performance Schema results display intermittently

Tags: mysql

Running queries against the performance_schema MySql tables and I'm finding that query results display intermittently. The user I am logged in with has select permissions. Another developer, with a different user, with the same permissions, connected to the same database was able to query with results. We are only seeing results in the replicate database under their user account.

When we run `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'performance_schema';` on the same database, on one account the value is OFF and the other the value is ON

We are using a AWS Aurora MySql database version 5.6.10

Comment: This question has nothing to do with programming, therefore it is off topic here on SO. The DBA sister site of SO provides help in database internals question like this.

Comment: Thanks! I will move my question.

Comment: For those interested parties who land here - AWS has a Performance Insights product, which enables Performance Schema features. If the db is clustered, there is potential only one instance has this feature enabled. Consider looking at the cluster details at each of the cluster members to see if you can connect to the instance which has Performance Insights enabled. Apologies for posting in the wrong location! I hope this helps others.